# Calculate distance between two points in bing maps

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps

Ihave a bing map, and a  two points :
Point1,Point2 and i want to calculate the distance between these two points? is that possible?
and if i want to put a circle on the two third of the path between point1 and point2 and near point2 ...how can i make it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) or even better the [Vincenty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae) formula how to solve this problem.

The following code uses haversines way to get the distance:

```
public double GetDistanceBetweenPoints(double lat1, double long1, double lat2, double long2)
    {
        double distance = 0;

        double dLat = (lat2 - lat1) / 180* Math.PI;
        double dLong = (long2 - long1) / 180 * Math.PI;

        double a = Math.Sin(dLat / 2) * Math.Sin(dLat / 2)
                    + Math.Cos(lat1 / 180* Math.PI) * Math.Cos(lat2 / 180* Math.PI) 
                    * Math.Sin(dLong/2) * Math.Sin(dLong/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));

        //Calculate radius of earth
        // For this you can assume any of the two points.
        double radiusE = 6378135; // Equatorial radius, in metres
        double radiusP = 6356750; // Polar Radius

        //Numerator part of function
        double nr = Math.Pow(radiusE * radiusP * Math.Cos(lat1 / 180 * Math.PI), 2);
        //Denominator part of the function
        double dr = Math.Pow(radiusE * Math.Cos(lat1 / 180 * Math.PI), 2)
                        + Math.Pow(radiusP * Math.Sin(lat1 / 180 * Math.PI), 2);
        double radius = Math.Sqrt(nr / dr);

        //Calculate distance in meters.
        distance = radius * c;
        return distance; // distance in meters
    }
```

You can find a good site with infos [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).

Comment: +1. Haversine is most common and is perfectly suitable for determining approximate distance between any two points. Vincenty gives a better approximation because it assumes the shape of the earth of is a spheroid rather than a perfect sphere. A final option is to import the Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll library and use the STDistance() method of the SqlGeography datatype. That will give the most accurate result as it uses an ellipsoid model (e.g. WGS84) - just the same as SQL Server does for the geography datatype.

Comment: Thanks it work great for the distance part, but how can i show a circle in the 2/3 of the distance between point1 and point2??

Comment: One problem I've found with this solution is that it can return NaN due to trying to take the square root of -1. It seems that there needs to be some tweaks to the implementation. If I end up fixing it I'll re-post the answer.

Comment: There seems to be an off by 2 error with this e.g. all distances are half what they should be ...

Answer (score 12):

Microsoft has a [GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.getdistanceto.aspx), which uses the Haversine formula.

For me other implementation return NaN for distances that are too small. I haven't run into any issues with the built in function yet.

Comment: Oh, didn't noticed that before. Thanx

Comment: The API is just getting to big! Didn't knew that one either and I've added a Haversine implementation in my own common lib to take along in my projects. Guess I can delete it know, sweet!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a geographic library for (re-)projection and calculation operations if you need more accurate results or want to do some math operations (e.g. transform a circle onto a sperioid/projection). Take a look at [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) or [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/) and the samples/unittests/sources there... this might help to solve your problem.

Anyway if you know the [geodesic distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) and [bearing](http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/calculating-bearing/) you can also calculate where resulting target position (center of your circle) is, e.g. see "Direct Problem" of [Vincenty's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Method) algorithms. Here are also some [useful algorithm implementations](http://studentguru.gr/b/kokyri/archive/2012/01/30/some-geometry-methods-for-working-with-coordinates.aspx) for silverlight/.net

You might also consider to post your questions at [GIS Stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/). They discuss GIS related problems like yours. Take a look at the question for [calculating lat long x-miles from point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5821/calculating-lat-lng-x-miles-from-point) (as you already know the whole distance now) or see the discussion here about [distance calculations](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3945/distance-between-lat-long-points). This question is related to the problem [how to draw a point on a line in a given distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/how-to-create-a-point-along-a-line-given-distance) and is nearly the same (cause you need a center and radius).

Another option is to use [ArcGIS API for Silverlight](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/samples/start.htm#Lengths) which can also display Bing Maps. It is open source and you can learn the things you need there (or just use them, cause they already exists in the SDK). See the Utilities examples tab within the samples.

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned: Take a look at [this page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to get more infos regarding your problem. There you'll find a formula, Javascript code and an Excel sample for calculating a destination point by a given distance and bearing from start point (see headlines there).

It shouldn't be difficult to "transform" the code to your c#-world.